# Civicrm PHP MySQL Driver (libmysqlclient) on WP

Tags: utf8mb4

after an upgrade of WP and Civicrm I am getting the following message:

PHP MySQL Driver (libmysqlclient)
It is recommended, though not yet required, to upgrade your PHP MySQL driver (libmysqlclient) to >= 5.5.3 for utf8mb4 support.

This is a message that also apprears upon making a new installation of Civicrm.

My environment from Phpmyadmin is as follows:

Database server
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.5.22-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: cpses_kee3y1i26i@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
Web server
cpsrvd 11.110.0.15
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.16
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 8.1.16

It looks like the utf8mb4 is already supported, so I am at a loss as to how to proceed.  Can you help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to use the command line to run `php -r "echo mysqli_get_client_info();"` and post what the output is? Because it seems like you have mysqlnd from the above, but civi seems to think you have libmysqlclient.

Answer (score 0):

All that I am getting is what looks like a version number:
3.1.22

[image: screen grab]

Comment: I guess that means you have version 3.1.22 of libmysqlclient. Ask your host if you can either switch to mysqlnd or upgrade the libmysqlclient.

Comment: Dear new user, please do not mess with answers (provide solution), comments (discuss post quality and information gathering) and post editing (provide more information).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I contacted the host and they applied the change you suggested and the error message disappeared.Thank you again.

Comment: I had the same issue and followed the instructions from @Demerit and my host said, "We would like to inform you that we have enabled the nd_mysqli PHP extension and now your website loading without any issues." Worked like a charm!